# How to add dynamic class in li element?

Tags: 8

**Need to add dynamic class in li element of below code like dymanic democlass1,democlass2...... so-on in loop.**

```
 <div class="rrssb">
 {% if prefix_text %}
 <div class="rrssb-prefix">{{ prefix_text }}</div>
 {% endif %}
 <ul class="rrssb-buttons">
{% for button in buttons %}
  <li class="rrssb-{{ button.name }}">
    <a href="{{ button.link }}" {{ button.class | raw }}>
      <span class="rrssb-icon">{{ button.svg | raw }}</span>
      <span class="rrssb-text">{{ button.text }}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
{{ loop.index }}
```

this will count up each time it goes through the loop